# Symfony 2.8 : DQL query to display an arraycollection

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I'm a beginner on Symfony 2 and I have a problem with a DQL query : I'm trying to display a property that is an ArrayCollection.

Here's my case : Two classes joined together with a "ManyToOne" and "OneToMany"

DishGrade.php :

```
/**
* @var Dish $dish
*
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dish", inversedBy="grades", 
cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dish_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
*
*/
private $dish;
```

Dish.php :

```
/**
* @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $grades
*
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DishGrade", mappedBy="dish", cascade={"all"},
orphanRemoval=true)     
*/
private $grades;
```

Then here's my controller which returns an array of objects "DishGrade"

```
/**
* Get grades dish.
*
*
* @ApiDoc(
*   output = "Awadac\ApiBundle\Model\Dish",
*   statusCodes = {
*     200 = "Returned when successful",
*     404 = "Returned when the dish is not found"
*   }
* )
*
* @Get("/dishes/{id}")
*
* @param Request $request the request object
* @param int     $id      the dish id
*
* @return array
*
* @throws NotFoundHttpException when dish not exist
*/
public function getDishAction(Request $request, $id)
{
$dish = $this->getDishManager()->getRepository()->getGrades($id); 

if (!$dish) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Dish does not exist.');
}
return $dish;
}
```

And here's my query that doesn't work :

DishRepository.php :

```
public function getGrades($id){


$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

return $qb->select('d.grades')
    ->from('AwadacApiBundle:Dish', 'd')
    ->where('d.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();


 }
```

the error code I get :

{"code":500,"message":"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'grades FROM AwadacApiBundle:Dish': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.","errors":null}

And when I want to get all the properties from my object "Dish" it works, so I just wonder why I can't display this ArrayCollection alone.

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already in the DishRepository you will be able to create the query builder by

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
```

Further just remove the ->from() statement and I guess it should work properly:

```
return $qb->select('d.grades')
        ->where('d.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: you are welcome! please don't miss to check my answer as "accepted" if it helped you! thank you in advance. regards

Comment: but if I remove the "->from" I get an error : 'd.id = :id': Error: Class 'd' is not defined.
When I change the line "select->('d.grades')" into "select->('d')" I can get all the properties from my Dish object, "grades" included. Now I just want to get the "grades" property :s

Comment: did you already add the 'd' alias into the createQueryBuilder method as shown upon?

Comment: No I didn't, my bad. 
I've changed it but I still get the same error that I had first : "code":500,"message":"[Semantical Error]......

Comment: Seems like you still access the method via _em property, aren't you? Explicitly use `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');` if you didn't yet.

Comment: I noticed that and remove the "_em" as well while adding the alias. the query with"select->d.grades" is still not working :s